# bash: command not found message

Tags: linux, bash, path, command, debian

i had freshly installed Debian 12, it was installed without error messages from netinst ISO and some command aren't find by the bash.

```
lm@debian:~$ sudo sh -c 'echo $PATH'
[sudo] password for lm: 
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin


lm@debian:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/lm/.local/bin
```

These are such a simple command as systemcntl, reboot, and even dpkg.
So, it need to manually improve path to them. For example, i had freshly installed rfkill package and it can't be found.

```
Preparing to unpack .../rfkill_2.38.1-5+b1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking rfkill (2.38.1-5+b1) ...
Setting up rfkill (2.38.1-5+b1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.11.2-2) ...
root@debian:/home/lm# rfkill
bash: rfkill: command not found
root@debian:/home/lm# sudo rfkill
ID TYPE      DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
0 wlan      phy0   unblocked unblocked
1 bluetooth hci0   unblocked unblocked
root@debian:/home/lm#
```

why it not find the command if it must be in /usr/bin, it's has included to Path & i have a superuser rights?

same for the next command:

```
root@debian:/home/lm# rfkill unblock 0
bash: rfkill: command not found
root@debian:/home/lm# sudo rfkill unblock 0
root@debian:/home/lm#
```

I had reinstalled this distro 6 times while this month (2 times on 3 machines each) but with the same result.

how can i fix this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. You wrote *"need to manually improve path"*. Please copy&paste how exactly you "improved" `PATH`. Show the command you typed or what file you modified in which way. Please copy&paste the output of `echo $PATH` (after a fresh login without any commands to modify `PATH`) and `sudo sh -c 'echo $PATH'`. How did you become `root`? Did you log in as `root`? Or did you run some `sudo` or `su` command? `rfkill` should be `/usr/sbin/rfkill` and `/usr/sbin` should be in `PATH` for `root`. Maybe you modified some script like `.bashrc` in a wrong way.

Comment: i didn't improwed path, it's still as is  before rfkill package was installed.

Comment: i didn't improwed path, it's still as is  before rfkill package was installed. And the question is not "how to improve the path" - it's well known thing, but why path cannot find the new installed package in default directories or why package manager didn't update path. of coarse, my path included /usr/sbin directory by default

Comment: i login as standard user I become root by su command, or use sudo if in standard user

Comment: The first code block with commands to show `PATH` doesn't seem to match the situation in the third block where the command is not found. (Seemingly user `lm` vs `root`) It may be normal that for a non-root user `PATH` does not contain `/usr/sbin`. Your prompt shows `root@debian:/home/lm#` Show the exact command how you came to this prompt and the output of `echo $PATH` in this situation. At this `root` prompt, when you run the `rfkill` command now, does it work?

Comment: try `su -` (don't forget the hypen) to become root.

Comment: see better, please. in both cases user is root.

Answer (score 1):

Your question/problem is not very understandable but from what I understand it is an environmental problem. I would even say that it's not a problem but a misunderstanding

**/usr/sbin/** and **/sbin** are accessible **only with elevated privileges** that's why to launch the rfkill command is not found in standard user.

@Grobu is right if you can't run the command as root, is that you don't have the root user environment.
this line confirms that you still have the lm user environment:

```
root@debian:/home/lm#
```

To switch the user environement use

```
su -
```

For example:

```
test@debian:/home/test$ su
root@debian:/home/test# rfkill unblock 0
bash: rfkill: command not found
```

but

```
test@debian:/home/test$ su -
root@debian:/root# rfkill unblock 0
root@debian:/root#
```

You don't have the problem with the sudo command because this command launches with the environment of the user root.

**It's not possible to launch the rfkill command as a standard user.**

If you want to be able to access the rfkill command from another user you don't have much choice:

- use sudo

Comment: from which place you are guessed, that i had launch the rfkill command as a standard user.? as you see, that prefix is "root" in all cases.

Comment: You are logged in as root but you do not have the full root environment to be able to launch all the commands. Use the "su -" command to retrieve the user's entire environment or use sudo. Look the man page for this command : https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html

Comment: You can be root without having the root environment, if you don't have the /sbin/ /usr/sbin paths in root, you don't have the root environment. Find out about the user environment. The command "su" (switch user), cleans up all variables, changes folder to the HOME of the substituted user and resets PATH,HOME, USER, LOGNAME and SHELL variables. In your case PATH has not been generated (/sbin and /usr/sbin is not present) and the home folder has not changed (/home/lm)

Comment: This is the difference between "su" and "su -". The first only changes user but does not change environment while the second changes the entire environment

Comment: in my /etc/login.defs there is lines ENV_SUPATH      PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
ENV_PATH        PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games  and output is root@debian:/home/lm# echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/lm/.local/bin:/root/.local/bin so i guess that there few places where it set.  how to check, which places is active now and clean all additional places, except /profile?

Comment: Check this documentation https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables